# JQuery Error: Object doesn't support method or property 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'**

I've done a lot of research for this specific error and all resources imply that either the JQuery library isn't getting loaded or 2 different versions of the library are being referenced for which the suggestion is to use the JQuery.noConflict() method to emcompass scope. Unfortunately, neither seem to resolve the behavior I'm receiving and I've spent considerable hours troubleshooting the issue without resolve.

I am using a MasterPage in ASP.NET and have tried placing the following script references in the MasterPage header as well as moving it to the content header of the actual Webpage. Another point maybe worth mentioning is that my script resides in a RadScriptBlock control. I wouldn't imagine it should make a difference though. I also have 1 simply div tag with the ID of the div assigned in the script.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainColumn" Runat="Server">
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        height: 240,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    });
});
</script>
</telerik:RadScriptBlock>

<div id="#dialog-modal" style="background-color: white; height: 300px; width: 300px;">
<asp:Label ID="lblText" Text="HELLO WORLD!" Width="300" Height="300" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

After some rearranging of the script references and eliminating conflicting versions, I was finally able to eliminate the annoying error. But I tagged titled this post with the orignal error because I believe the issue is still somehow related.

So what I get now is a visible div with a white label saying HELLO WORLD! upon the load of my page. Which leads me to believe that something is still broken. I should be getting a popup "Dialog" box upon load of the Page at the least.

I could remove the JQuery code to acheive the same results that I am now getting.

Another point worth mentioning is that even when I had the Unsupported Object method for the dialog error. If I replaced the function with the folowing I had no issues:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   alert('Hello World');
});
</script>
```

So I don't "think" that the resolution of the initial error actually resolved anything except that I don't any longer receive the Runtime error.

Any help is appreciated. Especially if you've seen or had this issue.

Comment: @user1848739 Control ID's should only change if `runat="server"` is present.

Comment: Have you tried changing your div's ID to `dialog-modal` instead of `#dialog-modal`? I believe your selector can't find it because of the `#` you have listed in the ID.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your observation was dead on. I was using code snippets from examples to get me up and running with the basics and so presumed that the syntax was correct. After removing the hash symbol from the ID tag it worked as expected. How can I give you credit for the response as an answer though? I don't see the option available. Do you need to repost as an answer as opposed to a comment?